# How to get current release context in azure devops extension api

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there anyway to get current release context without using releaseId on that release page? I can use ReleaseRestClient with getRelease(Id) to get the release info, but I want to know is it possible to get current page data without using releaseId? For example, in Build you can use IBuildPageDataService to get the build page data. Is there anything like IReleasePageDataService?

Comment: The rest API [Release - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) is not what you ask for but it should do what you looking for. It returns a list of all release of you project inside you collection, no release id needed.

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!).

Comment: I would like to get one specific release (e.g. release-1) info on the current release (release-1) page without using releaseId, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to get current release context without using releaseId
> on that release page?

Available Classes and Interfaces are listed in [azure-devops-extension-api package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/?view=azdevops-ext-latest). And as I know, there's no something like "IReleasePageDataService" can be used to get current release page data.

So I think you have to use `ReleaseRestClient` with releaseId to get the release info.